# Permission to view, but not to change! - Django

Tags: python, django, django-admin

is it possible to give users the permission to view, but not to change or delete.

currently in the only permissions I see are "add", "change" and "delete"... but there is no "read/view" in there.

I really need this as some users will only be able to consult the admin panel, in order to see what has been added in.

Comment: This feature is available in Django 2.1 https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/releases/2.1/#what-s-new-in-django-2-1

Comment: To understand the implementation of `has_view_permission`, it may be helpful to follow the discussions leading up to this feature, in the pull requests: [original](https://github.com/django/django/pull/5297) and [rebased](https://github.com/django/django/pull/6734)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Update**: Since Django 2.1 [this is now built-in](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/releases/2.1/#model-view-permission).

In admin.py

```
# Main reusable Admin class for only viewing
class ViewAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    """
    Custom made change_form template just for viewing purposes
    You need to copy this from /django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/change_form.html
    And then put that in your template folder that is specified in the 
    settings.TEMPLATE_DIR
    """
    change_form_template = 'view_form.html'

    # Remove the delete Admin Action for this Model
    actions = None

    def has_add_permission(self, request):
        return False

    def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return False

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        #Return nothing to make sure user can't update any data
        pass

# Example usage:
class SomeAdmin(ViewAdmin):
    # put your admin stuff here
    # or use pass
```

In change_form.html replace this:

```
{{ adminform.form.non_field_errors }}
```

with this:

```
<table>
{% for field in adminform.form %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{ field.label_tag }}:</td><td>{{ field.value }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Then remove the submit button by deleting this row:

```
{% submit_row %}
```

Comment: I followed this answer it removes add and delete button but not change button. And when I tried to remove change button in the same way (by returning false) it doesn't show the model at all!

Comment: You have to remove the link yourself (e.g with jQuery). The `save_model` method doesn't return anything so the user can't save. So even if they'd stumble across the link, they wouldn't be able to do any harm. Or maybe I didn't understand your question.

Comment: This is good , but Django docs say save_model should save or delete data and it should not be used for veto purposes. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-methods

Comment: @dan-klasson where to put these codes. i mean the first on in admin.py file in myproject and second one in django/contrib/admin/templates/change_form.html

Comment: @TameenMalik: See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates

Comment: This answer really needs to be updated, as this has been made much easier since Django 2.1. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/releases/2.1/#model-view-permission

Comment: @BenDavis Done.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [the django-admin-view-permission application](https://github.com/ctxis/django-admin-view-permission):

`pip install django-admin-view-permission`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'admin_view_permission',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    ...
]
```

UPDATE:

[Django 2.1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/releases/2.1/#model-view-permission) has a view permission out of the box.

Answer (score 3):

You can't just view things in django admin.

There is a [databrowse](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/databrowse/#ref-contrib-databrowse) app for that.

Comment: @Ryu_hayabusa it was deprecated, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17961791/as-django-databrowse-is-deprecated-in-django-1-4-is-there-a-better-way-for-data

Comment: link cannot be accessed

Answer (score 3):

One workaround would be to have an additional "save" permission on your model and check in the modeladmin's `save_model` method if the user has this permissions, if he has not, that would mean he can do everything in this modeladmin, except saving edited data!

Comment: that is an awesome idea!! Thanks! I think I might tick this answer as accepted :)

Answer (score 3):

To provide sample to Bernhard Vallant mention above. In my admin.py file I would place

```
class LogBookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display        = ['dateEntry','due_date', 'controlNo', 'carrier', 'status']    
    exclude             = ['encoder_status', 'engr_status', 'chief_status', 'ischecked']

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):     
        if request.user.groups.filter(name='Encoder').exists():
            pass
        else:
            return super(LogBookAdmin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

Assuming I have a group name `Encoder` where I would like them to view Logbook only. But other group name can save any changes.

Answer (score 3):

In django 2.1, you just need to override `has_change_permission` and `has_delete_permission` :

```py
@admin.register(MyModel)
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def has_change_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return False

    def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return False

    # to disable view and add you can do this 
    def has_view_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return False

    def has_add_permission(self, request):
        return False
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by following way:

1)You can make the fields read only if the object has been created.But doing this noone will be able to change the fields

2)You can use databrowse

3)You can use form validation ,if user is not in the selected list throw validation error if any field is changed

4)you can create a view ,if user is in your list then redirect it to normal flow or else redirect him to simple html readonly page

5)Use jquery to make the fields readonly is user is not in the list  and override the save method to check any smartness.In your save method you throw error any form has changed and user is not in your list.username=request.user.username

Answer (score 0):

You may also override ModelAdmin.change_view (as stated in the Django docs). Just make sure you also override save_model to make sure the user can't update the data

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33543817/101831

See https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/10539/

```
class ReadOnlyAdminMixin(object):
    """Disables all editing capabilities."""
    change_form_template = "admin/view.html"

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ReadOnlyAdminMixin, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.readonly_fields = self.model._meta.get_all_field_names()

    def get_actions(self, request):
        actions = super(ReadOnlyAdminMixin, self).get_actions(request)
        del actions["delete_selected"]
        return actions

    def has_add_permission(self, request):
        return False

    def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return False

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        pass

    def delete_model(self, request, obj):
        pass

    def save_related(self, request, form, formsets, change):
        pass
```

**templates/admin/view.html**

```
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block submit_buttons_bottom %}
  <div class="submit-row">
    <a href="../">{% blocktrans %}Back to list{% endblocktrans %}</a>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

**templates/admin/view.html (for Grappelli)**

```
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block submit_buttons_bottom %}
  <footer class="grp-module grp-submit-row grp-fixed-footer">
    <header style="display:none"><h1>{% trans "submit options"|capfirst context "heading" %}</h1></header>
    <ul>
       <li><a href="../" class="grp-button grp-default">{% blocktrans %}Back to list{% endblocktrans %}</a></li>
    </ul>
  </footer>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a workaround that needs to sacrifice the *change* only permission. In the admin template `change_form.html` I check for both *add* and *change* permissions in the template and display the `submit_row` only if the user has both permissions. Therefore, users with change permission only are able to view change_list and change_form, but never see the buttons to submit the changes they have made.

The changes I made:

- Create a directory in my apps templates directory like `myapp/templates/admin/myapp/`
- Pull in `change_form.html` in the directory
- Replace

  `{% block submit_buttons_bottom %}{% submit_row %}{% endblock %}`

with

```
{# Use change permission only as read only #}
{% if has_change_permission and has_add_permission %}
{% block submit_buttons_bottom %}{% submit_row %}{% endblock %}
{% endif %}
```

This is far from being clean and still allows the user to change data if other ways besides the standard admin form are offered, yet maybe its enough, if you just want to protect staff from accidentally changing data they should not.

Answer (score 0):

I can see with the proposed answers here, you'll face probably more problems than you need to make for yourself, as I tried all the aforementioned answers above myself. I finally figured away around this:

The way I did it, which you'll find in the [Django Admin Cookbook](http://books.agiliq.com/projects/django-admin-cookbook/en/latest/uneditable_existing.html), is to make the fields you want editable when creating/adding, but read only after. In other words, once you create the object, whatever fields you override in that method the link provides, will be read only and you won't be able to edit them once added to the database model.

Comment: `has_view_permission` [available as of Django 2.1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.has_view_permission)

Answer (score 0):

This is quite of an old thread, and most people already know this, but... Django 2.0 has build-in `view_permissions` [link to awesome view permissions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/releases/2.1/)