# Allowing user/users to only view one table of DB with Django?

Tags: python, django

I am very new with Django and trying to learn from various sources on internet. My project folder structure goes like [image]

I am using sqlite.db and made 6 models that are linked to backend DB. One of the table i have is Execution_Results.

```
class Execution_Results(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        permissions = (
            ('view_results', 'User can view results'),
        )
        verbose_name_plural = "Execution_Results"
    config_id = models.ForeignKey(Config_Details, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    exec_time = models.DateTimeField()
    path = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

With Admin login i can only provide access to add, edit and delete for that particular or group of users. For my case i just want view access for users. And based on whatever config_id they choose i want to read data from other tables based on mapping and present it for user.

I gave permissions = (
            ('view_results', 'User can view results'),
        ) but i am not getting what next shall be done so that user can just view this table data.

Answer (score 0):

I got this resolved without any setting or coding by just adding view permission module from git. Please refer answer at [Permission to view, but not to change! - Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068843/permission-to-view-but-not-to-change-django/49132957#49132957)

Comment: If another SO post answers this question you should close the question and not answer with a link to another question

Comment: I ca understand @DJK but there is no direct non coding answer to this question.