# Django 1.11 - make the whole site read-only for users from a given group (preferably with a fixture)

Tags: django, readonly, user-permissions, usergroups

My question is not the same with [View permissions in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23104449) because that one explains how to deal with the issue in Django 2.1 and higher which has a concept of "view" permission while I am working with Django 1.1. which does not.

Django 1.11

I have a group users who should have only read-only access to everything on the site. No restrictions on fields, models, and actial data, only what they can do with it (read-only). I know about possible implementations that suggest doing it "field-by-field" (or "make all fields read-only") and "model-by-model" solution. I am curios if there is a way to do it cleaner, on user group level, or at least on user level.

My views.py so far is default:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required 
def index(request):
    """View function for home page of site."""


    # Render the HTML template index.html with the data in the context variable
    return render(request, 'home.html')
```

Ideally, I'd like to be able to do this with a fixture.
Currently in the fixture, I have my groups defined like this:

```
{
    "model": "auth.group",
    "fields": {
        "name": "some_group",
        "permissions": [
            [
                "add_somemodel",
                "myproject",
                "somemodel"
            ],
            [
                "change_somemodel",
                "myproject",
                "somemodel"
            ],
            [
                "delete_somemodel",
                "myproject",
                "somemodel"
            ]

         ]
       }
}
```

In Django 2.2 I can do

```
{
    "model": "auth.group",
    "fields": {
        "name": "some_group",
        "permissions": [
            [
                "view_somemodel",
                "myproject",
                "somemodel"
            ]  
         ]
       }
}
```

but in Django 1.11 I have only "add", "delete" and "change" - no "view" option (according to the docs [enter link description here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#default-permissions)). So, is there a way to create a fixture that creates a group that has only read permissions for everything?

Comment: are you using django-admin

Comment: @c.grey I have 
`INSTALLED_APPS = [
...
    'django.contrib.admin',
....
]` in my settings.py if that's what you are asking

Comment: the permissions you show are only used in django-admin. To use them in your own views, you need to explicitly check them anyway. Nothing is stopping you from creating your own permission and checking it using (`has_perm()`) or to just create a special `Group` and check if the user is in that group. Check the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#programmatically-creating-permissions)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [View permissions in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23104449/view-permissions-in-django)

Answer (score 0):

In your view you need something like this(Notice that this is an example of how to view a post if you belong to the proper access group):

```py
def post_detail(request, slug=None):
    if not request.user.is_staff or not request.user.is_superuser:
        raise Http404
    instance = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
    share_string = quote_plus(instance.content)
    context = {
        "title": instance.title,
        "instance": instance,
        "share_string": share_string,
    }
    return render(request, "post_detail.html", context)
```

Pay attention to:

```py
if not request.user.is_staff or not request.user.is_superuser:
        raise Http404
```

Here are some link to the docs that will help you:

[How to authenticate users](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#authenticating-users)

[All attributes to django.contrib.auth](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/auth/#django-contrib-auth)

Edit:
I saw your code now, so what you want to achieve can be done like this

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required 
def index(request):
    """View function for home page of site."""
    # With that way although a user might be logged in
    # but the user might not have access to see the page
    if not request.user.is_staff or not request.user.is_superuser:
        raise Http404


    # Render the HTML template index.html with the data in the context variable
    return render(request, 'home.html')
```

That way a user may be logged in, but if it's not staff member or superuser it want have access to the page.

Comment: Not sure I understand. Where is it setting a specific group (or a user) as having only read permissions?

Comment: When you creating your models, for each user you can have a field of what he/she is. and then in the view you can have the check logic

Comment: This page describes exactly what you want https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/

Comment: Yes, that's 2.2. But Django 1.11 does not have "view" permission, only add, change and delete - or I am mistaken?

Comment: I can't understand what you are asking but here is for the version 1.11 I think is exactly the same https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/   . The  thing about django is that there is no huge gap between versions.

Comment: Sorry I probably should have stated that I am trying to achieve that with the fixtures. Updated the post

Comment: Also: check for is_stuff  and is_superuser as you suggest did not disable "Add <model>" button.

Comment: is_stuff and is_supersuer is an example I gave you. You can use anything you want from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/auth/#django-contrib-auth

Comment: @SwissNavy this is confusing me: are you talking about django-admin or your own views? ("add model" button is in django admin, but maybe it's something in your own view)

Comment: @SwissNavy [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068843/permission-to-view-but-not-to-change-django) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068843/permission-to-view-but-not-to-change-django)

Comment: @dirkgroten I was trying to see what's the easiest/cleanest way to configure a group members of which would be able to see all the data in all the models but won't be able to add, edit or create anything anywhere in Django 1.11. I am open to review any implementation, but my first thought was it should be doible with user/group/permissions setup in the DB only because I can do that for "add" and "delete". Apparently it's not the same for "view" in 1.11

Comment: No, “add” and “delete” permissions only have a meaning in the admin site. In your own views if you don’t do anything and creat a view to “add” a model, even users who don’t have the “add” permission will be able to create a model instance. Unless you check it explicitly in your view. So what I’m saying is, you have to do the same for “view”, except in addition you have to create a permission for it.

Comment: @dirkgroten I think I understood the difference you are talking about. Yes, I browse the models and entities in them from the admin.

Comment: So basically the `index` view has nothing to do with your question? you just want to have "view-only" functionality in django-admin? Then update to Django 2.2. There's no other easy way.

Comment: @dirkgroten Correct, index view code was in the question just to show that I did not add anything custom yet. Upgrade to 2.2 now is approved and scheduled this year :-). However, for the current setup the solution I came up with works.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everybody for responding. I did not figure out the way to do it with only user/group/permissions config in the db with Django 1.11, maybe it does not exist. Here is what I ended up with (very similar to the first suggestion I hit on SO when I started the research 4 hours ago, with minimal code changes)

1. Create a fixture for my new group that contains only "change_somemodel" permission and created a user as a member of that group, i.e. no "add_somemodel" and no "delete_somemodel" entries and load it into DB:

```
[
    {
        "model": "auth.group",
        "fields": {
            "name": "<my_new_group>",
            "permissions": [
                [
                    "change_<somemodel1>",
                    "<myproject>",
                    "<somemodel1>"
                ],

                [
                    "change_<somemodel2>",
                    "<myproject>",
                    "<somemodel2>"
                ]
             ]
    }
,
    {
    "model": "auth.user",
    "fields": {
        "password": "<my_password>",
        "last_login": null,
        "is_superuser": false,
        "username": "<my_username>",
        "first_name": "",
        "last_name": "",
        "email": "",
        "is_staff": true,
        "is_active": true,
        "date_joined": "2019-04-01T14:40:30.249Z",
        "groups": [
            [
                "<my_new_group>"
            ]
        ],
        "user_permissions": []
    }
}
],
```

This took care of the first part: now when I login as this user I do not have "Add new.." or "Delete" buttons anywhere for any model for my user.

2. Now, when I load a view for a given instance of some model, I still have the fields editable and I still see "Save", "Save and Add Another" and "Save and Continue" buttons. To take care of this, in `admin.py` in the superclass from which all my models are subclassed, in its custom `def changeform_view` I added:

```
if request.user.groups.filter(name='<my_new_group>'): 
   extra_context['show_save_and_add_another'] = False
   extra_context['show_save_and_continue'] = False
   extra_context['show_save'] = False
```

This made those 3 "Save" buttons disappear for all the models and made all fields read-only. Now this new user can not add, delete or edit anything for any model yet they can see everything, just as I wanted.

Looks like in the newer Django, starting from 2.1, this can be done even better.